# getting a add cannot be resolved or is not a field and ic_menu_refresh cannot be resolved or is not a field error

Tags: java, android

I am using eclipse and learning android out of a book.  I am copying code to learn about menus and am getting these two errors and cannot figure out why.

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    menu
    .add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ADD, Menu.NONE, "Add")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add);
    menu
    .add(Menu.NONE, MENU_RESET, Menu.NONE, "RESET")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_refresh);//error here.
```

This is the ic_menu_refresh cannot be resolved or is not a field error
ic_menu_refresh does not show up as one of the options ic_menu_add did.

The getting a add cannot be resolved or is not a field error

```
private void add(){
final View addView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(android.R.layout.add, null);//add is the source of the error.
```

Here are the libraries I am using

```
 package com.commonware.android.menus;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
  import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.ContextMenu;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
```

I can include the rest of the code if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you are most likely trying to use a resource that is not a public resource in the sdk. You can always pull it from your sdk on your machine and put it inside your drawables.

Your error in the second case is that you are using android.R instead of just R.  android.R is all of the android available resources included in the sdk. When you use just R.something you are referencing your programs R class to look for your resources. Make sure if you put just R that eclipse didn't import the actual android.R in the imports for the class. You want to import yourpackagename.R in the top of the class you are using them in.

Comment: I imported the packagename.R and I am still getting the same error

Comment: In the code did you remove the android part? Also have you created an add.xml file in your layouts folders?

Comment: Thanks that took care of that one, can you explain how I would pull the resource from my SDK and put it in my drawables?

Comment: Go to your sdk folder, a path like "C:\path to sdk\android-sdk\platforms\android-7\data\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_menu_refresh.png". This is the hdpi version from api level 7. There are a lot of resources in those folders. Take the file you find and put it in your app\res\hdpi folder. Then refer to it using R.drawable.ic_menu_refresh.